# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal-8\core\vendor\react\promise\src\functions.php on line 62

Tags: 8, installation

I have just installed Drupal 8 development version (drupal-8.0.x-dev) but while running it on my web server I am getting this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal-8\core\vendor\react\promise\src\functions.php on line 62
```

Line 62 has code:

```
59   return resolve($promisesOrValues)
60          ->then(function ($array) use ($howMany) {
61              if (!is_array($array) || !$array || $howMany < 1) {
62                  return resolve([]);
63              }
```

My PHP version is 5.3.8

Is there anybody else who has faced same issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Drupal 8 requires PHP 5.5.9 or higher (for short array syntax among other things).

You'll need to upgrade your version of PHP.

Source: [System Requirements](https://www.drupal.org/requirements)

Comment: yeah thats correct I missed that part...

Comment: That's correct, but the installer should tell you so instead of a fatal error. There's probably already a bug report about this, but would be great if you could check and report this if there isn't.

Comment: actually this error appeared just you hit http://localhost/drupal8 it even don't let you go to installer will check and report this bug.